# What is causing my WLST scripts to time out when updating node manager credentials?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x, wlst

I'm using WebLogic 10.3.6 (it's old, I know) with Java6 and am trying to install in a new environment.  I'm using WLST scripts that worked in other environments where the OS is the same (CentOS 5.11), SELinux is in permissive mode, and the application user has permission to write to the directory where all of the WLS stuff is saved.  Each time I try to update anything in the SecurityConfiguration MBean, it get a timeout when trying to activate.  Initially I thought it was just for the node manager credentials, but I tried to do

```
!> cmo.setClearTextCredentialAccessEnabled(true)
!> validate()
!> save()
!> activate()
```

Everything is fine until the activate... here's my results:
Activating all your changes, this may take a while ... 
The edit lock associated with this edit session is released 
once the activation is completed.

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in ?
  File "<iostream>", line 376, in activate
  File "<iostream>", line 1847, in raiseWLSTException
WLSTException: Error occured while performing activate : Error while Activating changes. : [DeploymentService:290053]Request with id '1,488,512,657,383' timed out on admin server.
Use dumpStack() to view the full stacktrace
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real issue causing this problem was the NFS where my binaries were being shared across instances.  The NFS was configured in a *VERY* non-standard way, causing all kinds of file read/write timeouts.